# How can I extract a particular frame from a WMV file?

Tags: php, wmv

I have a Windows Media Video file, and the need to grab a frame and show it. How might I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a ready made library available for that, however you can probably make use of ffmpeg.

http://www.db75.com/new_blog/?p=121

Comment: Link's busted. Any idea what was on the other end of it?