# Editing WMV metadata using Python or PHP?

Tags: php, python, video, wmv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [need a wmv php library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555714/need-a-wmv-php-library)

Is there library to edit WMV metadata using Python or PHP? I tried editing with ffmpeg but it just creates a new video file(with edited tags) rather than just editing the tags.

Comment: I've never done anything like this, but are you sure you can't tell it to write back to the input file?

Comment: @mcandre: That topic deals with grabbing a frame